# is there any other than querySelector and querySelectorAll that i can use

Tags: javascript, html

How can i run all these paragraph?

```
<p>Player 1: Test 1</p> 
<p>Player 2: Test 2</p>

const para = document.querySelector('p');
para.addEventListener('click', updateName);

function updateName() {
  let name = prompt('ENter your name');
  para.textContent = 'Player 1:' + name;
}
```

i know querySelector returns the first element but i want to know how can i return both paragraph. I already tried using querySelectorAll but i do not know how to write it.
Sorry iam still learning btw

Comment: *"I already tried using querySelectorAll"* - Not according to the code shown you didn't.  Can you demonstrate that attempt in a [mcve] and indicate specifically what isn't working as expected?

Comment: Sorry sir. I just randomly try and error by reviewing my copy paste code and self taught from youtube and google. And iam still trying to figure out how the code works. Sorry sir

Comment: Is there any way to restructure this code?

Comment: In general the advice would be to [use `querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), which will return a `NodeList` containing the matched elements, over which you can iterate and perform whatever operation you like.  Have you tried using `querySelectorAll`?  What attempt have you made and what specifically didn't work as expected?

Comment: Thank you sir i already got the answer.  I need to understand them better on how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what are you looking for:

```js
const paragraphs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('p'));
for (let index in paragraphs) {
  paragraphs[index].addEventListener('click', () => {
    const name = prompt('Enter your name:');
    paragraphs[index].textContent = `Player ${+index + 1}: ${name}`;
  });
}
```

```html
<p>Player 1: Test 1</p> 
<p>Player 2: Test 2</p>
```

Comment: @IdrisZaki you are welcome, accept the answer if it helped.